# Создание графической библиотеки своими руками

Tags: c++, windows, графика

Давно хотел попробовать с нуля создать свою простенькую графическую библиотеку типо OpenGL или там DirectX, исключительно из спортивного интереса(давно интересуюсь этой темой и как то писал простенький рендер трассировкой лучей на java, но сейчас хочу сделать отрисовку в реальном времени). может кто подсказать библиотеки для c++ ну или подскажите куда копать. Одной из целей является отрисовка вращающихся моделек формата obj. По сути, все что нужно от библиотеки-рисование точки заданного центра в заданных координатах, ну или формирование битмапа и его отрисовка целиком

Comment: Так написать с нуля или взять готовую?

Comment: [Рекомендую](https://habrahabr.ru/post/248153/).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо, отличная статья, но меня интересует не алгоритм визуализации, а способ рисования, в данной статье изображение выводится в файл, как я понял, а меня интересует отрисовка в реальном времени. Тем не менее мне будет полезно её почитать еще раз)

Comment: @Arhad Да я вроде ясно написал, что хочу написать свой велосипед с нуля, ездить я на нем не буду, а написать охота.

Comment: `меня интересует отрисовка в реальном времени` – ну так замените вывод в файл на вывод в окно с помощью `BitBlt`, плюс перерисовывайте минимум 24 раза в секунду. Всё равно большая часть статьи посвящена именно растеризации и проецированию.

Comment: если вам хочется API более низкоуровневое чем OpenGL, то попробуйте [Vulkan](https://www.khronos.org/vulkan/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не смотреть вглубь работы графических карт, не принимать в расчёт шейдера и прочие вещи, которые уже давно написаны и вылизаны до максимальной степени в графических библиотеках аля Direct3D / OpenGL, то можете попытаться писать на WinAPI, рисуя на контексте (HDC). ( Считай это наводкой ). Если хочешь ещё ниже к ядру оси, почитай про GDI и реализуй свой WinAPI.

Впрочем, нет смысла городить велосипеды, когда есть достаточно уже обкатанные рабочие либы, лучше воспользоваться ими. По опыту скажу, рисовал модели Maya ( это те самые *.obj ) и при помощи WinAPI, и при помощи OpenGL, на OpenGL это в разы быстрее.

Answer (score 0):

Неясно чего вы хотите, что `OpenGL` что `DirectX` не являются библиотеками, у них есть одинаковые функции, но по существу они отличаются хотя бы тем, что первый это стандарт по котору программируется графика на разных языка и кроссплатформенно, а второй - `DirectX` набор библиотек от майкрософта для написания мультимедийного софта.

> Одной из целей является отрисовка вращающихся моделек формата obj

Для этого будет вполне достаточно использовать `OpenGL 4.x` например, парсить `.obj` файл и применять базовые функции этого `API` для рисования примитивов, наряду с некоторыми базовыми матричными операциями для всяких пространственных преобразований

А написание своего `OpenGL` или `Direct3D` относится к разработке собственного рендера - грубо говоря набора низкоуровневых функций позволящих например, быстро отрисовать линию по [какому-нибудь алгоритму](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%B0) или [закрасить многоугольник](https://habrahabr.ru/post/116398/) каким-нибудь цветом - тоесть здесь совсем другие вещи применяются, в основном мало связанные с той типичной 3D математикой с которой сталкиваешься при непосредственном использовании `OpenGL` или `Direct3D`

Так что определитесь...

Comment: Так я и хочу написать собственный рендер(да да, хочу сделать свой велосипед), ну интересно мне это. А что на счет модельки, так это просто для примера, я понимаю, что можно юзать OpenGL, но я хочу это сделать, грубо говоря, используя только точки.